# Is /Z7 /LTCG:INCREMENTAL expected to cause LNK1103 errors?

Tags: visual-c++

For a while now, I have been getting weird LNK1103 linker errors in Visual Studio 2022 (and IIRC, same in Visual Studio 2017). The error message is

> foo.lib(bar.obj) : fatal error LNK1103: debugging information corrupt; recompile module

`for` and `bar` usually vary, but often include Windows libraries such as `kernel32.lib(KERNEL32.dll)` (certainly nothing that is built inside the same solution); and even if `foo.lib` *is* built by the solution, I was able to verify that the file used during a failed link attempt is identical to the same file from a successful build.

At one point, I noticed that this happens most often after adding or removing a function to one of the compilation units. And I ended up finding robust reproduction steps by adding one class after another and building each time:

`bug.bat`

```
@echo off

where MSBuild.exe 2> nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 call "%VS2022INSTALLDIR%\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"

rmdir x64 /s /q

set BUILD=MSBuild.exe Bug.sln /target:Bug /property:Configuration=Release -maxcpucount:1 -verbosity:minimal

:start

echo class Class%random% { void Method%random%() { } }; >> Bug.cpp

rem First iteration works
%BUILD%

rem After usually 1-2 iterations, we get a "fatal error LNK1103"
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

goto start

:error

rem Retrying *once* does not fix the problem...
%BUILD%

rem ... while retrying a second time usually fixes it, printing
rem "Previous IPDB and IOBJ mismatch, fall back to full compilation."
%BUILD%

pause
```

`Bug.sln`

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.5.33424.131
Project("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}") = "Bug", "Bug.vcxproj", "{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

`Bug.vcxproj`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456781234}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>Bug</RootNamespace>
    <ProjectName>Bug</ProjectName>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.22000.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <DebugInformationFormat>OldStyle</DebugInformationFormat>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="Bug.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
</Project>
```

`Bug.cpp`

```cpp
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
TEST_CLASS(Class) { TEST_METHOD(Method) {} };
```

What is notable is that the only thing that I need to do to fix this, is to retry *two* times, and that the second retry outputs

> Previous IPDB and IOBJ mismatch, fall back to full compilation.

Still, building from the command line should better work the first time.

LNK1103 is not super-popular on Google, but there were a few interesting hits. One is somewhat similar behavior in the Chromium project (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=644525), where disabling incremental linking reduced the frequency of the problem. Ultimately, it turned out to be a kernel bug that was fixed in Windows 10 1809, see more info at https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2018/02/25/compiler-bug-linker-bug-windows-kernel-bug/.  I am using 21H2, so I should be good here.

In an earlier, more complex example, I dug into linker settings and found that the issue occurs

- with `/LTCG:INCREMENTAL` (`UseFastLinkTimeCodeGeneration`)
- but not with `/LTCG` (`UseLinkTimeCodeGeneration`) nor with `/LTCG:OFF` (`Default`)

In the example code above (which implies `/LTCG:INCREMENTAL` via `<WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>`), I was further able to link the issue to the presence of `/Z7` (`<DebugInformationFormat>OldStyle</DebugInformationFormat>`).

Is that a known/expected error? Is it worth using `/LTCG` over `/LTCG:INCREMENTAL` (it seems *much* slower)? Can I make MSBuild retry (or fall back to full compilation) by itself? Should this be reported to Microsoft? Or should I investigate something I have missed so far?